# Banco de Dados Firebird com problemas

Tags: banco-de-dados, firebird

Tenho um Banco de Dados Firebird novo, implantado a menos de 60 dias, até então pouco usado, em um dia o seu tamanho era de 40 Megas, em menos de 6 horas acontece reclamação de usuários sobre lentidão no sistema, ao verificar o Banco de Dados esta em 126 Gigas. Como isso é possivel, o que pode estar ocorrendo? Alguma solução? Como verificar possíveis erros? Ao analisar aparentemente essas informações estão apenas em uma tabela, a qual logicamente nao consigo abriri devido a quantidade de dados.

Comment: Faz um teste, se você fizer um backup/restore da base, ela volta ao tamanho original?

Comment: Essa tabela é relacionada a o que? Há transações abertas consumindo esse banco? Porque há esse volume grande de dados?

Comment: Quase nao consigo manipular nenhuma informação em meu Banco, ele trava demais pelo seu tamanho, tive o mesmo problema a um tempo e o Banco teve 12 Gigas, fiz um backup/restore, ficou certo, voltou, porém preciso saber o motivo desses ocorridos.

Comment: Esta tabela em questão nao deveria possuir grande volume de dados, nao tenho campos Blobs e nem imagem nela. Nao sei se o problema é apenas nela.

Comment: O garbage collection está ativo? o seu banco tem muito insert/update ? isso me parece ser problema de lixo no banco.

Comment: Tem Bastante insert/update, mas neste caso o Banco pouquíssimo movimentado, e em relação a garbage collection  o Banco tem menos de 60 dias de uso, não acredito ser problema de lixo no banco tendo em vista que é pouco usado, tinha apenas 40 Megas.

Comment: Qual o "sweep interval"?

Comment: Como eu verifico qual é o sweep interval?